# Remove / replace special characters like # and also blank cells from the dataset in R

Tags: r, regex, special-characters

How do I remove special characters like # from a dataset in R?
I have dataset like this,

```
X Id           V1         V2
1 65          245         Good
2 41          245         Good
3 48          245            $
4 74          245         Good
6 54                      Good
7 60          245         Good
```

I tried to remove the special characters by using the following line

```
df2[, (1:3)] <- sapply(df2[, (1:3)], function(col) {
  as.numeric(sub("[*]$#", "", col))
})
```

but this is not working?
Is their any way to remove the blank cells as well using the above code or in one same line?

Comment: Hi user3448883, welcome to SO! If you want to get a quick answer, it would help to post a small example of the type of data you are working with, and exactly what you are looking for as far as output. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/554531

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With stringr try the following (on a string s):

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(s, "[[:punct:]]", "") # if you want to remove the punctuations
str_replace_all(s, "[^[:alnum:]]", "") # if you want to keep only the alphanumerics
```

Comment: why not `gsub()` ? though this is also perfect!

Comment: sure sub / gsub will also do from base R

Comment: It works, but how should i approach if i need to search and replace for the entire dataset? I dont know whether this approach itself works for that.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can apply the replace function for each column in the dataset